# Tagging a job in sidekiq for fast search and delete in future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

I have a use case where I would like to clear some sidekiq jobs when some event happens for a user in future.

One way to do it is to store the job_ids somewhere (say redis), and then search and delete jobs using that.

```
 Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job([job_id]).delete
```

But then I have to store it in redis, and search linearly among all jobs in queue.

Another way is to add an extra argument in the worker. Then search using that and delete.

```
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find {|j| j.queue == 'my_queue' && j.args[0] == "my_tag_user_id"}.map(&:delete)
```

This way, at least I don't have to worry about storing job ids in redis. But I don't it will make search any faster and seems a bit like a hacky solution.

I need suggestions on what can be the best way to tag some jobs for a given user in sidekiq and then search them fast later for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq's internal data structures are not optimized for this type of operation.  Instead, create a transaction ID for the jobs associated with the user and store it in your database.

```
tid = SecureRandom.hex(16)
user.update_column(:tid, tid)
10.times { SomeWorker.perform_async(user.id) }
```

When the future event happens, set a flag in Redis which signals that all jobs associated with this transaction ID should be cancelled.

```
Sidekiq.redis {|c| c.setex(user.tid, 2.weeks, 1) }
```

When the jobs run, the first thing they should do is check if they have been cancelled.  If so, they just return immediately without doing anything.

```
def perform(user_id)
  user = User.find(user_id)
  return if cancelled?(user.tid)
  do_stuff
end
```

Comment: Why need a tid column. If I am going to use redis as storage, I can directly store <user_id_some_name> as key pointing to a list of job ids to be deleted as value. And Then get the job ids from redis when event happens and delete the job using the job ids.

Comment: I agree with your point though, that sidekiq is not optimized for such operations. For now, I am going with the latter approach mentioned in the question by passing an extra arg and treating it as a tag. I did create 1 seperate queue for this use case, just to make searching a bit faster.

Comment: Because deleting a job by JID from Redis is incredibly slow at times.  Don't do it.  Yes, you can store the TID stuff in Redis, not the DB, if you want.